# Want to update and insert at the same tame, both of them not only one

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

I have a table where is stored information about countries, and i have to change ISO-code from 3 characters  to 2 characters  ISO-code.
for example i have data like this.

[image: this is how data is stored]

**and the question is**, first i want to update all of them which  are consisting of 3 digits set valid_until = '31.12.2019' and insert new row that should look like

[image: this]

Yes, I know that there is merge, but I need to update and insert, not only one.

Comment: Why can't you just write two statements and run both of them in that order? It isn't really clear what your problem is; it might be helpful to show your starting data and desired finishing data, for a consistent small set of countries - as formatted text please, not images.

Comment: I don't see any INSERT happening in your example, only UPDATE

Comment: Do you want to have both AD and AND rows when finished?

Comment: @jarlh, yes i want to keep both, just set that one is valid and another one isnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have another source for the codes, this is simply an insert/update:

```
update t
    set valid_until = date '2019-12-31'
    where length(iso_code) = 3;

insert into t (iso_code, valid_from, valid_to)
    select cs.iso_code_3, date '1940-01-01', date '3199-12-31'
    from t join
         codesource cs
         on t.iso_code = cs.iso_code_2;
```

You can wrap this into a single transaction, if you want them to take effect "at the same time".

Comment: yes something like this, the update does for all the same thats right, but how can i do the insert statement for all countries, i mean it should be automatic, if is possible

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Alex and Gordon that this can be run as 2 statements wrapped in a single transaction. So, not really clear on why this needs to be a single SQL statement. I've tried using duplicate rows in the `using` clause in `merge` to make the update and insert happen together (see snippet below). Please check if this is what you're looking to achieve.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e77de/3) here

```
    SQL> create table foo
      2  as
      3     select 'AD' iso_code,
      4            date '2020-01-01' valid_from,
      5            date '3999-12-31' valid_until
      6       from dual;


    SQL> select * from foo;
         |  ISO_CODE    |   VALID_FROM  |   VALID_UNTIL |
         |  AD          |   1/1/2020    |   12/31/3999  |


    SQL> alter table foo modify iso_code varchar2(3);

    SQL> create table iso_code_mapping
      2  as
      3     select 'AD' iso2_code, 'AND' iso3_code from dual;


    SQL> select * from iso_code_mapping;
         |  ISO2_CODE   |   ISO3_CODE   |
         |  AD          |   AND         |


    SQL> merge into foo
      2  using (
      3       select iso_code, iso3_code, valid_from, valid_until from foo f
      4                  join iso_code_mapping i on i.iso2_code = f.iso_code
      5              union all
      6              select iso_code||'_2' iso_code, iso3_code, valid_from, valid_until from foo f
      7                  join iso_code_mapping i on i.iso2_code = f.iso_code
      8                  where not exists ( select 1 from foo f2 where f2.iso_code = i.iso3_code and f2.valid_until = '31 DEC 3999' )
      9         ) x
     10  on ( x.iso_code = foo.iso_code )
     11  when matched then
     12      update set valid_until = '31 DEC 2019'
     13      where valid_until <> '31 DEC 2019'
     14  when not matched then
     15      insert (iso_code, valid_from, valid_until)
     16      values (iso3_code, '1 JAN 1940', '31 DEC 3999')
     17  ;


    SQL> select * from foo;
         |  ISO_CODE    |   VALID_FROM  |   VALID_UNTIL |
         |  AD          |   1/1/2020    |   12/31/2019  |
         |  AND         |   1/1/1940    |   12/31/3999  |
```